# Get all types that are used as generic type arguments

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get all types that are used as generic type arguments within certain assembly?

Basically, imagine I have this class:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    T SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I have an application and there I use the above in some way:

```
var stringFoo = new Foo<string>();
var intFoo = new Foo<int>();
```

Assume this is the only place the `Foo` is used. Now I would like to get type definitions of `Foo<string>` and `Foo<int>`. I.e. I want to find all types that are constructed from generic type definition (`Foo<T>`) within given assembly.

Is that even possible?

Comment: So you want to get the type arguments to `stringFoo` and `intFoo`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Reflection` should give you what you need or the base object class method `GetType()` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can't you just have your generic type implement an interface? You should be able to identify them that way.

Comment: @xanatos I think it's still more than I'm willing to do :)

Comment: It would be simplest (quick and dirty) to use "Find All" in Visual Studio searching for `ClassName<` to find every usage.

Comment: @JuanR I can, I was just wondering if it's easy to do something like: var types = Assembly.GetConstructredTypesFrom(typeof(Foo<>))

Comment: @Botis It wouldn't be very "useful"... so no :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction... Still a pain... But no extra libraries needed. Now... On top of my head there are various places where you could find a type `Foo<>`:

- attributes (`[MyAttribute(typeof(Foo<>)]`, or perhaps `Foo<>` is in itself an `Attribute`)
- base type chain (`class MyClass : Foo<int>`) or if `Foo<>` is a `IFoo<>` then implemented interfaces
- members of a type (fields, properties, events, methods) (here I mean only the signature part of those, so the field type, the method arguments and return type...)
- inner types of a type (types defined inside another type)

All of these can be found with "simple" application of reflection.

On top of these you can take a look at local variables of methods/properties (they are methods in the end), events (even they are methods in the end): if you have a `MethodInfo method`, you can get a `MethodBody body = method.GetMethodBody()`, and the `MethodBody` defines a `LocalVariables`.

Note that without disassembling the code (for example with [Mono.Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil)) you won't be able to detect that in

```
public class C
{
    public List<int> MyList;

    public void M()
    {
        MyList = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine(new List<int>());
    }
}
```

the method `M` uses a `List<int>()`, because no local variable of type `List<int>` is used. So in the end you'll need to even disassemble all the methods.

Clearly each time you find a type, you must check if the type is a `Foo<>`, a subclass of `Foo<>`, or perhaps uses `Foo<>` as a parameter (`List<Foo<>>`), or is a pointer `Foo<>*`, or a managed pointer `ref Foo<>` or...)

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as variables is concerned, you could discover the types by examining the method.

```
public static void GetGenericVariables()
{
    //Declaring two variables here that use Foo<>
    var inttype = new Foo<int>();
    var stringType = new Foo<string>();

    var methodInfo = typeof(ClassContainingMethod).GetMethod("GetGenericVariables");
    var variables = methodInfo.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables;
    foreach (var variable in variables)
    {
        if (variable.LocalType.IsGenericType && variable.LocalType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Foo<>))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(variable.LocalType.GenericTypeArguments[0].FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> System.Int32
>
> System.String

You would have to recurse over the assemblies and types though.